# Use Tag Controls in .NET

Tags: asp.net, tags

I've searched but cannot figure out what for now I'll call a "tag" control is in .NET. I want to build in the tagging feature you will find in most forums when posting a question (similar to stackoverflow). However I cannot find any info on it. I suspect its because I dont know what the technical name is for the control. They are called tags in forums. See screenshots. Can someone tell me if this is possible to build in .NET and what they are called. If not, what can I use to build this functionality?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That would/could likely be done using a jQuery plugin or the like.

Comment: The code for how stackoverflow's tags are drawn and work when clicked on is available.. on stackoverflow! Inspect the source code of the webpage and read/understand how it works then you'll be able to build your own. This isn't really a [VB].NET question, it's javascript/jquery or other page scripty and would be better tagged differently to reach a wider audience

Comment: Are you both saying there is not an asp.net object or control for tagging? I'm asking this as asp.net because I want to know if there is a control for it in asp.net. So it is an asp.net question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good [jQuery plugin named Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) that can do this Tag style using a multiple select asp.net control.

For example using the Chosen and this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    {
        jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({width: '100%;'});
    });
</script>

<asp:ListBox ID="lstWithTags" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

you have your tag select control very fast and easy